# How can i solve: "RCTBridge required dispatch_sync to load" in React Native using yarn workspaces?

Tags: react-native, yarn-workspaces, metro-bundler

i follow the medium article: [React Native 0.63 Monorepo walkthrough](https://medium.com/@ratebseirawan/react-native-0-63-monorepo-walkthrough-36ea27d95e26) carefully to get yarn workspaces works with react-native. Everhtings works, i can build my iOS und Android App and also the Metro Bundler works, but i get the following warning from the metro bundler when i build my iOS App with `yarn workspace mobile ios`

```
RCTBridge required dispatch_sync to load RCTDevLoadingView. This may lead to deadlocks
```

I don't get this warning unless I use react-native with yarn workspaces. Therefore, I suspect that the error is generated by my monorepo setup.

Do you have any idea how I can remove this warning?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open Your `/ios/YourAppName/AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

// ADD THIS
#if RCT_DEV
#import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
#endif
// TILL HERE

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

...
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                            moduleProvider:nil
                                             launchOptions:launchOptions];
// THIS CONDITION
#if RCT_DEV
  [bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
#endif
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"Test"
                                            initialProperties:nil];
// TILL HERE
  ...
}
```

source [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16376)

Comment: Solved my issue.

Comment: Make it the selected answer @Niklas

Comment: This did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Initially open `./ios/{YourAppName}/AppDelegate.m` and add the following after the `#import "AppDelegate.h"`

  #if RCT_DEV
  #import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
  #endif
- Then in the `@implementation AppDelegate` before the `RCTRootView *rootView = ....` add the following

  ```
  #if RCT_DEV
    [bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
  #endif
  ```
- Finally, reopen the terminal and `yarn run ios` or `npm run ios` again.

Answer (score 0):

After reopen the terminal and build the app again, the warning no longer appeared